# can not modify the member value of struct array in C programming

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct book
    {
        char bookID[20];
        char name[20];
        double price;
    };

void input(struct book bs[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    printf("Please input the price of book %s:\n",bs[i].name );
    scanf("%f",&bs[i].price);
    }
}

void print(struct book bs[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%.2f\n", bs[i].bookID, bs[i].name, bs[i].price );
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    book books[4] = {{"0101","Computer",1.5},{"0102","Programming",4.1},{"0103","Math",3.3},{"0104","English",1.2}};    
    input(books, 4);
    print(books, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I input ANY price of four books, the print function always output the default value: 1.5, 4.1, 3.3, 1.2

Wondering where is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `scanf("%f",&bs[i].price);` -> `scanf("%lf",&bs[i].price);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code, as you use the wrong [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format for reading into a `double`.

The correct format for [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and `double` is `"%lf"`.

---

Note that for `printf` it doesn't matter, `"%f"` and `"%lf"` are both valid for `float` *and* `double`.